# Unable to Downsample audio file in CGI perl script using sox

Tags: perl, cgi

I am working on a cgi script where I get an **uploaded** an audio file, **downsample** it to **8000Hz** and then get it recognised later.

I am facing an error while downsampling the file. The code for downsampling goes like:

1) Code for File Upload:

```
use CGI;
use strict;
use File::Copy qw(copy);
use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';
my $PROGNAME = "file_upload.cgi";
my $cgi = new CGI();
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
my $upfile = $cgi->param('upfile');

# Get the basename in case we want to use it.
my $basename = GetBasename($upfile);

no strict 'refs';

if (! open(OUTFILE, ">../cgi-bin/upload/".$basename) ) {
    print "Can't open for writing - $!";
    exit(-1);
}
```

2)Code for downsample:

```
my $source_file="/var/www/cgi-bin/upload/$upfile";
system("sox $source_file -r 8000 /var/www/cgi-bin/upload/temp.wav".";"."mv /var/www/cgi-bin/upload/temp.wav $source_file");
```

where:

1. source_file is the path for uploaded audio file
2. `$upfile` is the name of the uploaded wav file
3. temp.wav is the temporary downsampled file which is overwritten on the original file using mv command

**Error**

> sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `/var/www/cgi-bin/upload/file1.wav': WAVE: RIFF header not found

file1.wav is the file I uploaded

Please help me understand why the **sox** command is not executing despite it being correctly written?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code that saves the `$upfile` to disk. I believe you are missing a `binmode` on your output filehandle, or that data is otherwise mangled. Also run the `file` program on one of those uploaded files and tell us what it thinks this file contains.

Comment: did you look at the switch `-t <file-type>`

Comment: @simbabque Okay I have edited it and added the file upload code, that I am using. The uploaded file information shows: file1.wav: audio/x-wav; charset=binary. On Sox file information it shows: Channels : 1, Sample Rate : 11025, Precision : 16-bit

Comment: You forgot the part where you write to the file handle. That's three most important line.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yes I had tried with -t <file-type>, but it gives me the same error

Comment: what filetype did you put after `-t` ?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard i used -t wav <filename>

Comment: is it not wave?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer to your question as we don't have enough information yet.

Have you tried running the command from your Unix command line? I'd assume you get the same error. What do you get if you run `file` on the file that you have saved? How big is the file before and after you upload it?

You don't show the code that writes the uploaded file. I suspect there's a bug in that. If you add that to your question, we could help you find it.

Where is `GetBasename()` defined? Can we see the code?

Your `sox` command seems strange. You're running `sox` on a file called `temp.wav` and then copying that file over your uploaded file. Perhaps there are a couple of steps that you aren't telling us.

Some other suggestions for improvement:

- Use `cgi->new`, not `new CGI`. The latter has some strange corner cases that you will have real problems debugging if you ever come across them.
- If you're loading the `CGI` module, then why not use its `header` method instead of writing your own (technically incorrect) header.
- `no strict 'refs'` is a really bad idea (and, as far as I can see, isn't needed here).
- Please use the three-arg version of `open()` and lexical filehandles

  ```
  open my $out_fh, '>', "../cgi-bin/upload/$basename"
  ```
- Include the file path in your error message

  ```
  my $file = "../cgi-bin/upload/$basename";
  if (!open my $out_fh, '>', $file) {
    print "Can't open file '$file' for writing - $!";
    exit(-1);
  }
  ```
- You are loading the `File::Copy` module, but then moving your file using a shell command.
- Allowing random users to upload files into a directory under your `cgi-bin` directory is a massive potential security hole. You should find another directory to store the uploaded files.

Oh, and then there's the whole - why on Earth would you be writing CGI programs in 2017!

Comment: Thanks firstly for your response. I liked most of your suggestions and will improve my coding style, since I am in college and just started with perl a few days back unlike you who has more than 25+ years of experience.

Comment: Now coming to the code its working fine if I dont include that sox command. By fine I specifically mean, I am able to upload the audio file and run the necessary scripts to get the audio recognition. The reason for using sox is to downsample an uploaded file to 8000Hz(which is a prerequisite for me). The reason for using File::Copy  is that I was trying to copy the file to a particular location but I wasnt able to.

Comment: For copy function I am using "use File::Copy qw(copy);"                                I am defining the parameters for copy function as:                                      my $source_file="/var/www/cgi-bin/upload/$upfile";
my $target_file="/var/www/cgi-bin/output/$basename"                          where $upfile is the upload file and $basename is folder where I want to copy the $upfile. My copy command goes like:               copy($source_file ,$target_file) or die "Move failed: $!";  I am getting no error message for copy function in logs but clearly its not copying the file.

Comment: The parameters of copy function have correct values(I checked). Is it that the file is not uploaded completely and I call copy function too soon? I tried with sleep(n); too.

Comment: @PrabhjitThind: Adding information like this in comments isn't really helpful. It's hard to read code in comment. Far better to update your question to include this information.

Comment: And finally as a perl consultant who has worked for almost all the major companies in UK what should I used if not CGI(referring to the last line of your answer)?

Comment: See [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) (written by the current maintainer of CGI.pm).

Comment: @PrabhjitThind: It would be useful for you to write up the solution as an answer to this question (it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question - and even to accept that answer). Stack Overflow exists as a resource of answers to help programmers with problems. If someone else has a similar problem in the future, it will be frustrating for them to find your question, but no definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time Dave. But you didn't suggest me viable alternatives for cgi as asked in one of the comments,

Comment: @PrabhjitThind: I did.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. The reason why I was having problem executing the sox and copy commands was because of where I was placing the two commands in code. Basically a beginners error. So I was opening the file as mentioned in the problem statement. I put the copy and sox commands for execution before I closed the filehandler and hence they were not getting executed successfully.